# useNavigate takes 2 clicks to go back to previous page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate("page");
```

That's how the useNavigate is used in my app. It takes 2 clicks to go back to the previous page.

Why is that?

Comment: Can you share some more code? How are your routes organized? On what route do you do this navigation? Do you have some intermediate route which does some conditional redirection? Please add a minimal reproducible example snippet in the question. Also, please share a reproducible [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) link.

Comment: If I had to guess, the code you are using likely somehow enqueued ***two forward*** navigation actions. We can't help diagnose or debug code we can't see though, so please do try to edit the post to include a complete [mcve] so we've better context what the code is doing.

Answer (score -2):

i prefer to use

> "/page"

before

> "page"

Also please share onclick function because, i think it may be problem of that. Please also share console.log images, because sometime error shown their..
Thanks

Comment: **Preference** doesn't address OP's problem. Maybe OP wants some relative re-direction. Also, please ask clarifying questions in comments and not as an answer.